# How to deny some commands from a specific IP address?

Tags: server, permissions, iptables, hosts, snort

I was inspecting some browsers securities and while entering a game page my snort rules detected this.

[image: Snort in a nutshell]

It was something about an privilege escalation from this server. I don't want to block it, because I want to access them. Is there some way to block privileges from this server without using IPTABLES DROP?